# How do I use pouchdb with typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, couchdb, pouchdb, node-modules

I am trying to use pouchdb with Typescript.  I cannot link to the pouchdb module.

```
import { PouchDB } from "pouchdb"
```

reports that it cannot find module pouchdb, even though it is in node_modules.

I also cannot find the appropriate typings for pouchdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the module recognised by using

```
declare function require(a)

var PouchDB = require("pouchdb")
```

I have given up type checking, but at least I can make progress.

Comment: Have you had any luck? i have the same issue, it's kinda working but need to reload page on new browser for data to appear.  @LeRoy i've tried your method with no luck. Lot's of people having the same issue. I'm using angular2.

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing this in Ionic, so I may be missing a step on getting the types file loaded properly.

Make sure your types are installed with:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/pouchdb
```

At the top of your data service import pouch like so:

```
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

*** edit ***

I don't have all the facts, but this is my current understanding.
Typings is no longer needed in Typescript >2.0
I believe typescript now works automatically with types files installed from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).
[DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) is an official central repository that is kept current like npm.
And even if I'm dead wrong about all this, [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) is still better than typings and has a much bigger community.

Comment: This has helped me, when no other methods did using TypeScript and Angular2.

Answer (score 3):

Cause i just had this Problem, For Angular 2 + Typescript the correct way to use PouchDB (using angular-cli) is to:

1. `ng new SOMENAME`
2. `npm install --save pouchdb`
3. `npm install --save-dev @types/pouchdb`
4. In your app.component `import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';`
5. In your App Component Class `public db: any;` and to init `this.db = new PouchDB('test'); // , {storage:'persistent'} not working in typescript without updating typings`

see https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find/issues/201.

If you have problems installing the packages on windows with an EPERM Error use (f.e.) `npm install --save pouchdb --no-optional` to disable the warning. The installation should still be ok. For more info see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17671

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem trying to import into Angular 6.

Your imports seem fine:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchFind from 'pouchdb-find';
PouchDB.plugin(PouchFind);
```

What you may be missing is you need to add this to your `polyfills.ts` file:

```
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = {};
(window as any).process.nextTick = setTimeout;
```

Comment: The pollyfills sorted it out for me

Answer (score 1):

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

export abstract class PouchDBDatabase {
    private _database: PouchDB.Database<Sheet>;

    constructor(protected DATABASE_URL: string) {
        this._database = new PouchDB(this.DATABASE_URL);
    }
}
```

[image: auto-completion with typescript]

And  you're good to go with typescript + pouchDB :)